# Cannot get the id of a username Discord JS

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```
let string = `${args[1]} ${args[2]}`
console.log(string)
const idofuser =  client.users.cache.find((u) => u.username === `${string}`).id
```

My friends Discord Name is Like "Avex Sports" and DiscordJS says: cannot read property "id" of undefined, i would appricate any help

Comment: `.find()` is returning `undefined`, so you can't chain `.id` after it. Sidenote, you don't need interpolation here: `u.username === \`${string}\``, can just be `u.username === string`.

Comment: you mean so : "client.users.cache.find((u) => u.username === `${string}`).id"

Comment: No, exactly as I wrote it above: `u.username === string`, so `client.users.cache.find((u) => u.username === string).id`. You don't need to wrap a single variable in `\`{}\``; it's unnecessary. That was just a syntax sidenote and isn't a solution to your issue. Your main problem is that `.find()` isn't returning anything, so either `string` doesn't contain what you think it does, or `u.username` doesn't match `string` (i.e. you don't have a user with that username in `users.cache`

Comment: sry i meaned client.users.cache.find((u) => u.username === string).id

Comment: and what i should do if it not contains the username what i am searching for?

Comment: Check before you try to access ID. `let user = client.users.cache.find((u) => u.username === string);`, then `if (!user) { // do something } else { // do something with user.id }`. Never assume something exists; `find()` can return `undefined`, it's never guaranteed to return an Object.

Comment: yeah it works now, but how do i fetch it maybe? the error, like: "No username found" or something like that, because the if(!user) is useless because he breaks it just

Comment: That I don't know; I've never worked with `discord.js`. That's why all of this is a comment-thread and not an answer. I've nudged you in the right direction by fixing the immediate error, but I'm afraid I'm not sure what you should do next :)

Comment: its fine but thx man it helped me a bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets start with the string. What you did here works but only if the name you want to find has two words. If you want to use a name with more or less words then this will not work. So we can `.slice(1)` here assuming that the name really starts at the second argument.

```
let string = args.slice(1).join(" ");
```

Next we try to find the user object. Here you should use a `.toLowerCase()` on both sides of `===` to make sure that you don't run into capitalization problems.

```
let user = client.users.cache.find(u => u.username.toLowerCase() === string.toLowerCase());
```

Lastly we check if the user actually exists because, as said in the comments, you can never assume that something exists. If the user does not exist we `return` here and send a message that replies to the author.

```
if (!user) {
  return message.reply("That user doesn't exist!");
}
// The rest of your code
```

If the user does exist then you just continue with whatever you want to do here.

See here https://discordjs.guide/ for more information.